# Animations triggered from Gestures not working on PageViewController's children views

Tags: ios, animation, uicontainerview

I am using [THIS LIB](https://github.com/bfeher/BFPaperButton) for button, Now I have a viewcontroller, which has a container view, and this container view embeds(segue) a PageViewController, the 2nd page (which is another ViewController) in this PageViewController has the BFPaperButton (which has the ripple animations when onTap gesture). The animations don't work in this setup, but if were to make the 2nd Page's ViewController as the `Is Initial View Controller` then the animations works perfectly, what is going on here??

**EDIT**

I further isolated the issue, it seems this only happens when using a PageViewController and returning the ViewController containing the button in one of the data source delegate methods of PageViewController,

and it would seem the cause is most definitely the PageViewController, it seems its blocking some gesturerecognizers or delaying them for its child views, need to find out how to fix it.

Comment: I've solved this and would like to answer the question

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing. Do note that having solved your issue is not enough to reopen it - You have to actually provide the MCVE.

Comment: @Kyll I've already solved the issue, vote to reopen the question so that I can answer it :)

Comment: But the point is that, once reopened, others could also answer it... Maybe better than you even. To do so, they need a decent basis to work on. Plus, providing a MCVE would help future readers relate to your issue and greatly increase the usefulness of your question.

Comment: @Kyll isn't the information provided clear enough?? Animations on a child view of a PageViewController triggered from some Gesture X on this child view isnt working, I dont understand what else I need to add

Answer (score 0):

The effect that you describe is quite common when dealing with certain types of parent views that delay the content touches of their child views. The solution is usually as simple as setting the parent view's property: `delaysContentTouches`.

I would remember this because 9 times out of 10, this is the culprit.

However, in the case of UIPageViewController, what you are seeing is the default behaviour of a **`UIQueuingScrollView`** which does not expose that property. An ugly but effective way to get around this is to dig through the subviews of your `UIPageViewController` until you get to one that has some `UIGestureRecognizers`, and setting `delaysTouchesBegan = NO`.

You could do this by simply running this code after you initialize your `UIPageViewController`

```
NSArray *subviews = self.pageViewController.view.subviews;
NSArray *viewHierarchy = [@[self.pageViewController.view] arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:subviews];
int i = 0;
for (UIView *viewToCheck in viewHierarchy) {
    for (UIGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer in viewToCheck.gestureRecognizers) {
        NSLog(@"%d gestureRecognizer: %@", i++, gestureRecognizer);
        gestureRecognizer.delaysTouchesBegan = NO;
    }
}
```

here is a quickly slapped together Swift version if you prefer:

```
let subViews: [UIView] = pageViewController.view.subviews
var viewHierarchy: [UIView] = [pageViewController.view]
viewHierarchy.appendContentsOf(subViews)
var i = 0
for viewToCheck in viewHierarchy {
     viewToCheck.gestureRecognizers?.forEach { (recognizer) in
         print("viewToCheck isa \'\(viewToCheck.self)\'")
         for gestureRecognizer in viewToCheck.gestureRecognizers! {
             print("\(i) gestureRecognizer: \(gestureRecognizer)")
             i += 1
             gestureRecognizer.delaysTouchesBegan = false
          }
     }
}
```

Answered by github user [bfeher](https://github.com/bfeher)  , [for this issue](https://github.com/bfeher/BFPaperButton/issues/26)